# Npgsql assembly error in Classlibrary output type

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, npgsql

I have to connect to postgresql via Npgsql provider in nunit test, but I'm facing an assembly error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql,
>   Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or
>   one of  its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.
>   The assembly  may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but
>   not fully signed with  the correct private key. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131045) at PostgresTest.Testink.ConTest()

If I change application output type to Console Application everything works correctly.

1. I've checked dll in bin path -  Npgsql.dll is in bin path
2. I've tried    different net versions(>=4.5.1)
3. I've tried to use xunit - the same problem

Guys, any ideas what am I doing improperly?

```
[Test]
public void ConTest()
    {
        var connString = "Host=127.0.0.1;Username=root;Password=pwd;Database=database";

        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();             

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with the building of 4.0.1 ([see issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2031)) and will be fixed in 4.0.2 (to be released in a few days). In the meantime stick with 4.0.0.